# Failed to connect docker url with PHP Unit

Tags: docker, phpunit, docker-compose, drupal-8

I can access my site in the browser with the following path: `my-dash.docker.localhost:8000`.  Also, as I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732448/cant-access-docker-url-via-curl-or-postman) in order to access the site via POSTMAN I had to add to my host file:

```
127.0.0.1 my-dash.docker.localhost
```

I updated my phpunit.xml:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://my-dash.docker.localhost:8000"/>
```

When I run my test I get the following error:

```
1) Drupal\my_dashboard\Tests\Rest\MyDashboardResourceTest::testPost
GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to my-dash.docker.localhost port 8000: Connection refused (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)

/var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:186
/var/www/html/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:150
```

I verified that if I add a know url, I don't get this error:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="https://www.google.com/"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer [here](http://docs.docker4drupal.org/en/latest/containers/php/).  Updated phpunit.xml:

```
<env name="SIMPLETEST_BASE_URL" value="http://nginx"/>
```

Also in my case, I was using Drupal and had trusted hosts set in my settings.php.  I also had to add nginx as a trusted host.